# Plotting a time period histogram in Pandas

Tags: python, histogram

I have a relatively large data set of accidents, which contains a column called 'Time'. Each row has a 'time'. I would like to plot a histogram showing the frequency distribution of time periods. These are datetime objects.

On x-axis I would have time-periods, or starting of time periods. And on y-axis the number of rows/datapoints that fall in those time periods. Don't think of this as a bi-variate data, with time serving as index. Think of just one series - Time. I only need frequency distribution. All the questions and answers relate to some data in context of time-series. But, data is really not relevant here.

Comment: Can you please provide data, and an attempt along with what in particular you can't figure out?

Answer (score 1):

This worked. It was pretty straightforward.

```
df['Time'].hist(bins=24)
```